# Cannot get value of the body from backbone post url to nodejs

Tags: node.js, backbone.js

I am learning backbone and nodejs, using the url
https://addyosmani.com/backbone-fundamentals/#talking-to-the-server

I am trying to save the data of the book, While submiting the form, the values saved in collection and the db using node. the `collection.create(formData)` is the code for create collection and post the data in node. While I am trying to post, the formData contains an value, But in node getting the body object is empty.

In the learning program the nodejs is lower version I am using the higher version(4.x)

View Code:

```
var app = app || {};
app.LibraryView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '#books',
    initialize: function(){
        this.Collection = new app.Library();    // UPDATED
        this.Collection.fetch({reset: true});
        this.render();
        this.listenTo( this.Collection, 'add', this.renderBook );
        this.listenTo( this.Collection, 'reset', this.render ); // NEW
    },
    events: {
        'click #add': 'addBook'
    },
    render: function(){
        this.Collection.each(function(item){
            this.renderBook(item);
        },this);
    },
    renderBook: function(item){
        var bookView = new app.BookView({
            model: item
        });
        this.$el.append(bookView.render().el);
    },
    addBook: function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var formData = {};
        $( '#addBook div' ).children( 'input' ).each( function( i, el ) {
            if( $( el ).val() !== '' )
            {
                if(el.id === 'keywords' ){
                    formData[ el.id ] = [];
                    _.each($(el).val().split(' '), function(keyword){
                        formData[ el.id ].push({keyword : keyword});
                    });
                } else if( el.id === 'releaseDate'){
                    formData[ el.id ] = $( "#releaseDate" ).datepicker('getDate');
                } else {
                    formData[ el.id ] = $( el ).val();
                }
            }
            $( el ).val('');
        });
        console.log('sending FormData :', formData);
        this.Collection.create(formData);
    }
});
```

And My server Code:

```
var app_root = __dirname,
    express = require('express'),
    path = require('path'),
    mongoose = require('mongoose');var app = express();
mongoose.connect('mongodb://admin:password@ds025263.mlab.com:25263/myworks');
var Keywords = new mongoose.Schema({
    keyword: String
});
var Book = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: String,
    author: String,
    releaseDate: String,
    keywords : [Keywords]
});
var BookModel = mongoose.model('Book', Book);
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var methodOverride = require('method-override');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));
app.use(methodOverride());
app.use(express.static(path.join(app_root,'./','site')));
app.get('/api',function(req, res){
    res.send('Library Api is running...');
});
app.get('/api/books',function(req,res){
    return BookModel.find(function(err,books){
        if(!err){       
        console.log('total : ',books);  
            return res.send(books);
        }else{
            return console.log(err);
        }
    });
});
app.post( '/api/books', function( request, response ) {
    var title = request.body;
    var book = new BookModel({
        title: request.body.title,
        author: request.body.author,
        releaseDate: request.body.releaseDate,
        keywords: request.body.keywords       // NEW
    });
    console.log('before -- save : ', title);
    console.log('before -- save : ', request.body.author);
    console.log('before -- save : ', request.body.releaseDate);
    console.log('before -- save : ', request.body.keywords);
    console.log('before -- save : ', book);
    console.log('before -- save : ', book);
    book.save( function( err ) {
        if( !err ) {
            console.log( 'created' );
            return response.send( book );
        } else {
            return console.log( ' after - save : ',err );
        }
    });
});
app.get('/api/books:id',function(req,res){
    return BookModel.findById(req.params.id, function(err, book){
        if(!err){
            return res.send(book);
        } 
        else{
            return console.log(err);
        }
    });
});
app.put( '/api/books/:id', function( request, response ) {
    console.log( 'Updating book ' + request.body.title );
    return BookModel.findById( request.params.id, function( err, book ) {
        book.title = request.body.title;
        book.author = request.body.author;
        book.releaseDate = request.body.releaseDate;
        book.keywords = request.body.keywords; // NEW

        return book.save( function( err ) {
            if( !err ) {
                console.log( 'book updated' );
                return response.send( book );
            } else {
                console.log( err );
            }
        });
    });
});
app.delete('/api/books/:id', function(req, res){
    console.log('Deleting book with Id : ', req.params.id);
    return BookModel.findById(req.params.id, function(err, book){
        if(!err){
            console.log('Book Removed');
            return res.send(book);
        }else{
            console.log(err);
        }
    });
});
var port = 3000;
app.listen(port, function(){
    console.log('Server listening on the port %d in %s mode', port, app.settings.env);
});
```

My console while submit the output
In node

```
before -- save :  {}
before -- save :  undefined
before -- save :  undefined
before -- save :  undefined
before -- save :  { _id: 57dfa0d7aa34452730647e29, keywords: [] }
before -- save :  { _id: 57dfa0d7aa34452730647e29, keywords: [] }
Mongoose: mpromise (mongoose's default promise library) is deprecated, plug in your own promise library instead: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html
```

In Backbone

```
Sending FormData : Object {title: "sathish", author: "sathish", releaseDate: Thu Sep 01 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time), keywords: Array[1]}author: "sathish"coverImage: "img/backbone.png"keywords: Array[1]releaseDate: Thu Sep 01 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)title: "sathish"__proto__: Object
```

my whole project is here -- 
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BzZNadB85XQVdjJPRE9ra2FpLWc
Thanks in advance

Comment: You need bodyParser.json() it's similar to bodyParser.urlencoded but works with json which backbone is most probably sending to server, see this https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser/blob/master/README.md#bodyparserjsonoptions

Comment: Thanks @Molda It works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `app.use(bodyParser.json());` in server.js file.